# Check property for null LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code that give me data from database:

```
var t = (from ula in proxy.eUserLoginAttempts
         where ula.Date >= DateTime.Now && ula.Email.ToLower().Contains("")
         && ula.User != null
         && ula.User.Client != null
         && ula.User.Client.prStatus == 1
         select ula).ToList();
```

In this case, I would get prStatus from Client entity and I check User and Client object if they are not null. Should I do it or **ula.User.Client.prStatus** will translate in Inner Join and this check is needless?

Comment: is this linq to sql or entity framework?

Comment: why not to look at SQL Profiler?

Comment: `ula.Email.ToLower().Contains("")`??

Comment: If you are using C# 6.
var t = (from ula in proxy.eUserLoginAttempts
         where ula.Date >= DateTime.Now && ula.Email.ToLower().Contains("")
        ula.User?
         && ula.User.Client?
         && ula.User.Client.prStatus == 1
         select ula).ToList();

Comment: @akemp: doesn't look like valid C# to me. And the point of this question is whether it's possible that `User` (or `User.Client`) is ever null, since this is an expression tree translated to an SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your direct question: NO, you should test the nullable first...
About your code, I really do suggest a readable way:

```
var t = proxy.eUserLoginAttempts
    .Where(ula => ula.Date >= DateTime.Now)
    .Where(ula => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ula.Email))
    .Where(ula => ula.User != null)
    .Where(ula => ula.User.Client != null)
    .Where(ula => ula.User.Client.prStatus == 1)
    .ToList();
```

Or even better with C# 6

```
var t = proxy.eUserLoginAttempts
    .Where(ula => ula.Date >= DateTime.Now)
    .Where(ula => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ula.Email))
    .Where(ula => ula.User?.Client?.prStatus == 1)
    .ToList();
```